# remove method for binary search tree does nothing

Tags: python, binary-search-tree

```
class BinaryNode:
def __init__(self, value):
    self.data = value
    self.left = None
    self.right = None

def contains(root, value):
    if root is None:
        return False

    if value == root.data:
        return True

    if value < root.data:
        return contains(root.left, value)
    else:
        return contains(root.right, value)


def insert(root, value):
    if root is None:
        root = BinaryNode(value)
    else:
        if value > root.data:
            if root.right is None:
                root.right = BinaryNode(value)
            else:
                return insert(root.right, value)
        else:
            if root.left is None:
                root.left = BinaryNode(value)
            else:
                return insert(root.left, value)

def getMin(root):
    if root.left is None:
        return root.data
    return getMin(root.left)

def remove(root, value, parent = None):
    if root is None:
        return False
    elif value < root.data and root.left is not None:
        return remove(root.left, value, root)
    elif value > root.data and root.right is not None:
        return remove(root.right, value, root)
    else:
        if parent.left is not None and parent.right is None and \
           root.left is None and root.right is None:
               root = None
               parent.left = root



def inorder(root):
    if root is not None:
        inorder(root.left)
        print(root.data)
        inorder(root.right)


b =  BinaryNode(10)
insert(b, 8)
insert(b, 11)

remove(b,11)

inorder(b)
```

I'm in the process of writing my remove function for a binary search tree and i am 100% positive it is the correct implementation logic wise. I have implemented the most basic case of deleting a leaf node. The issue has to be python related ? when i try to delete 11, it still prints it in the inorder traversal.

Comment: Have you debugged line by line to see what the remove function does? I think the function is missing most of the code for actually removing things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Logic for removing a node lacks necessary steps. Please find below the code to remove a node:

```
def remove(root, value, parent):
    if root is None:
        return False
    elif value < root.data and root.left is not None:
        return remove(root.left, value, root)
    elif value > root.data and root.right is not None:
        return remove(root.right, value, root)
    else:
        if value == root.data:
            if root.right is not None:
                removeRoot = root.right
                while(removeRoot.left is not None):
                    parRoot = removeRoot
                    removeRoot = removeRoot.left
                root.data = removeRoot.data
                parRoot.left = None
                del removeRoot
            elif root.left is not None:
                parent.left = root.left
                del root
            else:
                if parent.right is not None and parent.right.data == root.data:
                    parent.right = None
                elif parent.left is not None:
                    parent.left = None
                del root
```